# Using Custom setting in vf page

Tags: apex, map

I have a custom setting Test__c with below fields -

Term__c, Price__c,BD__c

I want on the combination of Term__c, BD__c i should fetch the Price__c.

Below is the code i am using -

```
List<Test__c> alltest = Test__c.getall().values();
Map<String,Decimal> CP = new Map<String,Decimal>();

for(Test__c bp: alltest){
CP.put(bp.BD__c, bp.Price__c);
}
```

How i can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this logic and create key based on `term` and `BD`.

```
List<Test__c> alltest = Test__c.getall().values();
Map<String,Decimal> CP = new Map<String,Decimal>();

for(Test__c bp: alltest){
    CP.put(bp.Term__c + bp.BD__c, bp.Price__c);
}
```

To retrieve the Price from the map

```
CP.get('<term value>' + '<BD value>');
```

Comment: Hi Santanu...I dont have a combination on BD__c & Term__c in my custom setting..From vf page.. I will be selecting Term__c & BD__c and then i want the price__c to get fetched...The above code will throw a Argument cannot be null error...

Comment: Hi Santanu...I dont have a combination of BD__c & Term__c in my custom setting. I have separate fields ....From vf page.. I will be selecting Term__c & BD__c and then i want the price__c to get fetched...The above code will throw a Argument cannot be null error...

Comment: at your question you have specified that you have `Term__c, Price__c,BD__c` fields in custom settings. I have given an example how to create a map with the combination of term and BD